# In var = func(), Is func() evaluated right away or when var is needed?

Tags: python

I have following code

```
def isIt(arg):
    isA = funcA(arg)
    isB = funcB(arg)

    return (isA and isB)
```

where funcB() is way more computationally expensive than funcA and for more than half cases funcA() is False.

So it make sense if I make python call funcB only when funcA is True by

```
def isIt(arg):
    return (funcA(arg) and funcB(arg))
```

Are those two function same if resourse consumption is taken into account ? What if funcB() is any() on a generator ?

EDIT 1:
My intention to write like first code is that, parameters to funcA() and funcB(), which is not arg , is quite long, enought to break readability.

ps. I just realized that I can make two local functions instead of variable to achive the same effect like second code.

Comment: can you rephrase that question? What are you trying to determine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Are those two function same if resourse consumption is taken into account?*

They aren't the same functionally.  You seem to have understood this in the question, so I'm not quite sure what you are doubting, but this is especially important when resource consumption is considered:

```
def isIt(arg):
    lightweightResult = lightweightFunction(arg)
    expensiveResult = superExpensiveFunction(arg)

    // obviously you can use both results here, so both have been computed.


    // return the values directly, no further computation done here:
    return (lightweightResult and expensiveResult)
```

One reason you might do it this way is if you need `expensiveResult` for something else, or if `superExpensiveFunction` is always needed to be called, such as an initializer for some resource.

In the second case, as you've described, `funcB(arg)` is only evaluated if `funcA(arg)` is evaluated to true (returns a truthy value).  This is called [short circuiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation):

```
def isIt(arg):
    return (lightweightFunction(arg) and superExpensiveFunction(arg))
```

Short circuiting is well known to be a good way to prevent unnecessary execution.

> *What if funcB() is any() on a generator?*

It would never run the generator unless any is called.  Generators are already a good way to prevent unnecessary execution, since they are lazily evaluated.  I think short circuiting and generators make a good combination in this case.

As noted in the comments by [Blkknght](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18928436/in-var-func-is-func-evaluated-right-away-or-when-var-is-needed/18928539#comment27948422_18928539), it's worth noting that `any()` and `all()` also have short-circuiting, so in a generator, the generator would only be evaluated up to the element that confirms the result (false on all or true on any).  You can see the code at [python.org...#all](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all).

Comment: Your point about generators is good. If `funcB` is `any(expensive_generator(lots, of, args))`, you might call `gen = expensive_generator(args)` first (which won't do anything other than return the generator object), and just put the `any(gen)` call that consumes it into the short-circuting `and` expression. It might also be worth noting that `any` short circuits too, so if the first "truthy" value is early in the results of the generator, the rest won't ever be read.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it as

```
def isIt(arg):
    if not funcA(arg):
        return False
    return funcB(arg)
```

This is a bit longer, but fits the Python philosophy more.

*Edit:* made it three lines instead of five.

Comment: If I was reading this code, I would wonder why you wrote it in five lines instead of `return funcA(arg) and funcB(arg)`.

Comment: In what way does this fit the Python philosophy more?

Comment: @NikC, "explicit is better than implicit".

Comment: @flornquake, branch coverage analysis, for one. Also you don't need to remember about the short-circuiting every time you read it. I do not save on lines, I save on developer's time (mine as well).

Comment: @Bogdan What is implicit about the first?  That's basic programming logic, pretty universally understood.

Comment: @Bogdan I find the shorter version easier to read and understand in this case.

Comment: @flornquake, it's my personal opinion, I do not enforce it. Some people find ``while(++*p++) {}`` readable. My code anyone can skim through and subconciosly understand what it does. With short-circuiting, you have to stop for a second and remember this implementation detail.

Comment: @Bogdan actually to me short circuiting is far more readable and memorable. In fact, it is so common to execute functions in conditionals in most languages that it's essential for it to be second nature to mentally interpret.  Your revised code is far better than before, but it still illustrates the point that once you go beyond a single expression, logic can be written so many different ways that it will always be more mental effort to interpret.

Answer (score 0):

They aren't equivalent. The first one will call both `funcA` and `funcB` in every single case. The second one will call `funcB` only if the result of `funcA` isn't truthy, as the logical OR short-circuits.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are right to call the less computationally expensive function first

Here is how I would write the function:

```
>>> def isIt(arg):
...     if funcA(arg):
...             return funcB(arg)
...     return 0
```